# Shopping cart not updating the quantity from second attempt onwards

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, copyonwritearraylist

I'm trying to implement shopping cart process using two java classes. One is `CartItem` and the other one is `ShoppingCart` which holds all the process of the cart.

Here is my `CartItem` :

```
public class CartItem implements Serializable {

    private int pro_id;
    private int qnty;


    public CartItem(int pro_id, int qnty) {
        this.pro_id = pro_id;
        this.qnty = qnty;

    }
    // getters and setters
    ....
        // checking the item is already in the cart or not
        public boolean isSameProduct(CartItem item) {
        return this.pro_id == item.getPro_id();

    }
```

My `ShoppingCart` class:

```
public class ShoppingCart {

    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<CartItem> itemList;


    public ShoppingCart() {
        this.itemList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<CartItem>();

    }
    // adding item something wrong here I think..
    public boolean addItem(CartItem item) {
        boolean flag = false;
        if (!this.itemList.isEmpty()) {
            for (CartItem itm : this.itemList) {
                if (itm.isSameProduct(item)) {
                    itm.setQnty(item.getQnty() + itm.getQnty());
                    flag = true;
                   break;

                } else {
                    this.itemList.add(item);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
        } else {
            this.itemList.add(item);
            flag = true;
        }
        return flag;

    }

    public void removeItem(int item_id) {
        for (CartItem item : this.itemList) {
            if (item.getPro_id() == item_id) {
                this.itemList.remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the way I am adding products and the out-put :

```
ShoppingCart sc = new ShoppingCart();
sc.addItem(new CartItem(1, 1));
sc.addItem(new CartItem(1, 2));
sc.addItem(new CartItem(1, 3));
sc.addItem(new CartItem(1, 1));
sc.addItem(new CartItem(2, 1));
sc.addItem(new CartItem(2, 2));
sc.addItem(new CartItem(3, 4));
sc.addItem(new CartItem(3, 1));
 // sc.removeItem(3);

for (CartItem item : sc.itemList) {
    System.out.println("Item id - " + item.getPro_id() + " : Item Qnty - " + item.getQnty());
}
```

**Out-put:**

```
Item id - 1 : Item Qnty - 7
Item id - 2 : Item Qnty - 1
Item id - 2 : Item Qnty - 2
Item id - 3 : Item Qnty - 4
Item id - 3 : Item Qnty - 1
```

**But Expected :**

```
Item id - 1 : Item Qnty - 7
Item id - 2 : Item Qnty - 3
Item id - 3 : Item Qnty - 5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Either by stepping through it line by line in debug mode or using print statements to track the program's behaviour at each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a single item in the cart, you never actually check anything after the first item in the cart, because you always break whilst looping through the list elements:

```
        for (CartItem itm : this.itemList) {
            if (itm.isSameProduct(item)) {
                itm.setQnty(item.getQnty() + itm.getQnty());
                flag = true;
               break;  // It was the same product; break.

            } else {
                this.itemList.add(item);
                flag = true;
                break;  // It wasn't the same product; break.
            }
        }
```

Instead, you need to make use of `flag`'s value, and only add the item if `flag` is false:

```
public boolean addItem(CartItem item) {
    boolean flag = false;
    for (CartItem itm : this.itemList) {
        if (itm.isSameProduct(item)) {
            itm.setQnty(item.getQnty() + itm.getQnty());
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!flag) {
        this.itemList.add(item);
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```